# Atom editor : autopep8 is not working and no error message at all

Tags: python, atom-editor, autopep8

I install autopop8 in Atom. I got NO error message. Console in  developer tools is just clean no error or whatsoever. it's just silent and autopep8 is not working (turn on 'format on save' already). At the bottom of the editor , there's small autopep8 button showed up with red cross. I don't know what it means, click it but nothing happen. No clue at all. Just nothing to inspect . Does anyone can help to track what happen ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Step1:- First of all, you need to make sure that autopep8 module is installed in your PC, You can check this by using
`python -m autopep8 --version`
. If you can see the version then you can go to Step 3.

Step2:- You need to install autopep8 using the command line
`pip install --user autopep8`

Step3:- In the command line type `where.exe autopep8` and copy that path to the **Autopep8 Path** which is present in the setting of Autopep8 package.
[Snippet of Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oehGo.png)

Comment: This was my problem. After using this command the executable was saved in a file path not included in PATH so I manually moved it to a proper path and it worked fine. I don't like that solution though.

Answer (score 3):

This was really annoying to fix, as I kept installing it using the normal `pip install autopep8`, but atom never recognized it.

To fix this, I went to the github page of autopep8. On the page it said to install using the command: 
`pip install --upgrade autopep8`

Next it recomended I had to install the dependency of pycodestyle, which I did in the same way:
`pip install --upgrade pycodestyle`

Using this method fixed the problem for me, but make sure you use both commands as installing autopep8 with this method does not install the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to Atom --> Preferences --> Packages, scroll to the settings of python-autopep8.

My issue was my Autopep8 path was incorrect. When I ran:

```
pip install autopep8
```

in my terminal, the install location was in my `/usr/local/bin` directory. So in Atom my path should read `/usr/local/bin/autopep8`.

That fixed the problem. When solved, that little red "x" turned into a grey check mark for me.

Comment: sorry to ask stupid question but what does that mean "So in Atom my path should read /usr/local/bin/autopep8" ??

Answer (score 2):

Try with `pip3 install autopep8` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

After installing with --upgrade flag (which upgraded to higher minor version 1.43 -> 1.44) it worked fine

```
pip install --upgrade autopep8
```

Answer (score 0):

Im another noob here too: ). A youtube recommendation to close and reopen to fix this issues. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DjEuROpsvp4
I found that worked once for me, then not working again in a new project.

Answer (score 0):

After installing autopep8 if you have problem.Type 'which autopep8' in terminal you will get the path, place it in package settings executable autopep8  ,I think there is bug I had the same problem , i placed the path but it still shown the problem I tried to keep other paths and ran the beautify it gave errors I tried changing different ,but at last I kept again the one which I tried first the path given by which autopep8 now this time it worked ,why I don't know

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to keep your questions clear and short, so that others can understand them and focus on providing only the context needed to answer the question at hand.